# Does $2^k+2$ generate infinitely-many numbers whose digit sums are prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I'm stuck starting this problem:

> A number is considered "bad" when the sum of its digits is a prime. (Example: 131.) Show whether $2^k+2$ will generate an infinite amount of *bad*, or finite amount of *bad*.

Comment: try listing out the first five numbers in the sequence

Comment: Yeah I've tried that, I haven't found a definite pattern. 

k = 0,5,11,15 work so far.

Comment: @xpoes What do you mean by "works"? Do those give you bad primes, good primes, or non primes?

Comment: Is that sequence correct? $2^k+2$ is always even

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Are you looking for $k$ such that $2^k+2$ is prime and the sum of its digits is also prime?

Comment: $2^k+2$ won't be prime because that will always be even, I just want to find whether or not there there is an infinite amount of "bad primes" K is just any integer that works, I'm not concerned about the values of k

Comment: k = 0,5,11,15 give you "bad primes" as does 25.
k cannot be 0 mod 2 because then 2^k+2 would be 0 mod 3 which is no bueno

Comment: Referring to a composite number as a "bad prime" is confusing.  Why not just call it "bad"?

Comment: You misunderstood the question.  The question was what you define to be a "bad prime."  If someone hears something called a "<adjective> <noun>" then people commonly assume that it is a subcategory of a <noun>.  In your case however, it sounds as though "bad prime" is not necessarily a prime at all, and that confused people when reading for the first time, thinking you are wanting a bad prime to be a prime whose digit sum are also prime.  Consider: mersenne prime, twin prime, balanced prime, irregular prime, pillai prime, etc... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Classes_of_prime_numbers

Comment: Okay thanks, I fixed it to only say bad now.

Comment: As an interesting aside, primes whose sum of digits are also prime in base $b$ appear in [this paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Harman/harman2.pdf), and they are apparently called [additive primes](http://oeis.org/A046704)

Comment: I got a program to come up with solutions and this is what it came up with.

5,11,15,25,29,47,49,51,53,67,71,79,81,91,93.97

Comment: Is there any reason to imagine that this has a pleasant solution?  There doesn't appear to be any obvious way to construct such a number, nor any reason why arbitrarily large examples shouldn't exist.  Of course, maybe there's some clever trick..

Comment: No, possibly not. It's just been a problem I've been thinking about for a few days

Comment: The problem was proposed by one of my math friends, and he doesn't have a solution either.

Comment: Post this on math overflow.

Comment: odd number of odd digits required.

Comment: Computationally, the "bad" numbers of the form $2^k+2$ can be listed upto a very high limit, but it would be a miracle if it could be verified whether the number of them is finite. You will have to be content with a heuristic.

Comment: @xpoes Would a list upto a large $k$ satisfy you ?